# SIGNERR при подписывание транзакции в TronMainnet

Tags: python, tron

Выдаёт эту ошибку раз через раз. Не понимаю что делать. Подписываю транзакцию через tronpy

При send_transactions выдаёт
`{'code': 'SIGERROR', 'txid': 'fc4fd650b7f8c4e1cd7e5dd6c893c0d1b47ba619c0c63450ea98cba34fbdacf6', 'message': '56616c6964617465207369676e6174757265206572726f723a2065383935306161616135376366323662326234616335313233656637643238643265643765653662313361396530656435646362623532333737373765333233303332616432336338646138613233303536633736376333376665666362306336636430663034373530633161323731313030663036663435343538393663653031206973207369676e6564206279205448383762766b7a5642415a377461324371784b746963646d585a4b6d46324c6b7120627574206974206973206e6f7420636f6e7461696e6564206f66207065726d697373696f6e2e'}`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.